# load images dynamically in JavaFX to Anchorpane

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, javafx-2

I have this button where when i want to add images dynamically to my AnchorPane , but currently it's not working as expected. I'm trying to load an image inside JavaFX label, here is my code.

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    public AnchorPane pane;

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

      //   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("2d.png"));
      Label label = new Label();
      Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("2d.png"));
      label = new Label("search", new ImageView(image));
      pane.getChildren().addAll(label);      
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="521.0" prefWidth="548.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="testingcards.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Click Me!" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <Label layoutX="143.0" layoutY="366.0" prefHeight="121.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="Label" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Error

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)   at
>   javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)  at
>   javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)  at
>   javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)    at
>   javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)    at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)     ...
>   48 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   testingcards.FXMLDocumentController.handleButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:46)

I'm using netbeans IDE

Comment: Instead of _replacing_ the `Label`, why not _update_ the `ImageView` using `setImage()`?

Comment: `public AnchorPane pane;` is not marked with `@FXML` annotation, therefor it is not inserted by the loader, therefor it is null, hence the `NullPointerException`. Furthermore the image loading can also cause it.

Comment: @trashgod i tried that as Aza Suhaza said, but didn't worked, what will be the reason?

Comment: @DVarga i added `ImageView` solution as Aza Suhaza said, but didn't worked. I got an error `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create ImageView or if you're using scene builder, drop an ImageView into the AnchorPane area. Assign ID for the new ImageView;

In your controller class;

```
  @FXML
  ImageView imageId;

  @FXML
  private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
      Image img = new Image("../img/img.jpg");
      imageId.setImage(img);
  }
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer but i am getting `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

Comment: oh, thanks it worked, i had an issue with image path

Answer (score 1):

If that method doesn't work you can use this.
I have tried most of solution I can find online but those didn't work for me.

I have converted the file-path to a file and used that as a source.

```
String imgAddress = "C:\\Users\\Name\\onclickimageloader\\car.jpg";
String tmpAddress;

File file2 = new File(imgAddress);
tmpAddress = file2.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
Image image = new Image(tmpAddress);
imageId.setImage(image);
System.out.println(tmpAddress);
```